# Extra-Random JSON Parsing

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to parse a *very long* segment of JSON returned from a Helpdesk system, which I have no ability to modify. I have, thus far, been using the `JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Ticket>(data)` method in C#, but the problem I run into is the variance in JSON that will come back at me. Specifically, some properties have seemingly random sub-properties. What follows is a trimmed down version of obscured data illustrating this:

```
{"ticket_id":"12345","custom_fields":[{"customgroup_id":"12","custom_group":[{"customfield_id":"33","custom_field_data":{"customfield_data_id":"12345"}},{"customfield_id":"34","custom_field_data":{"customfield_data_id":"12345"}},{"customfield_id":"35","custom_field_data":{"3":{"customfield_data_id":"12345"}}},{"customfield_id":"54","custom_field_data":{"customfield_data_id":"12345"}},{"customfield_id":"55","custom_field_data":{"6":{"customfield_data_id":"12345"}}}]}]}
```

[image: Strange JSON]

Properties not relevant have been removed. As one can see, sometimes `custom_field_data` immediately follows with the array containing `customfield_data_id`, but some times it is followed with a completely random integer, and *then* the array with `customfield_data_id`. My problem is that I have no idea how to parse this -- thus far, I have simply mapped the JSON with corresponding classes, but considering the fact that it appears to be completely random whether or not those integers will get in between the `custom_field_data` and its list, I haven't a clue how to parse this.

If there is a way that preserves my current work in making Class Maps, that would be preferred. If the only solution is to completely switch over to some other library/method, then so be it. Thank you all for the assistance!

Comment: If you [generate c sharp classes based on this json](http://json2csharp.com/) you will get a class for `custom_field_data` with various properties for each "number" property that have their own class (the linked generator will give you classes named `__invalid_type__3`). You could write a method on your `custom_field_data` class that accesses the inner list by either using that property directly or through one of the "number" properties, depending on which one is null, but it's a bit hackish. The alternative is writing your own custom json serializer for this class.

Comment: Please, do not paste code as images

Comment: @Chronicle aye that's what I was using, and noticed those strange classes. I'll probably go the custom route, thank you. And Pavel, I only posted the image because it's JSON and would probably be impossible to decipher based on that one long line. Just a visualization. Still bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't create a C# class that match 100% with the JSON object. Your best option is to write your own custom JSON converter (System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter) as supported in .NET CORE. Have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-polymorphic-deserialization

Basically, it allows you to step through each JSON node 1 by 1 and you decide where to parse the value (put it in property of a class, or in Dictionary, or Array).